# background image isn't showed with the creation of the directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my directive

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('backgroundImage', Background);

    function Background () {
      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.backgroundImage, function(value) {
          element.css({
            'background-image': 'url(https://example.com/' + value + '.jpg)',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
            'background-position': 'center center',
            'background-attachment': 'fixed',
            '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
            '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
            '-o-background-size': 'cover',
            'background-size': 'cover'
          });
        });
      };
    }
}());
```

which I call from the view with the following code

```
<div background-image="id"></div>
```

My issue is that despite the image has been loaded correctly it isn't showed into the view. Do you have any idea?

Comment: why you dont use a css class and then `ng-class` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `height` as well, in order for the background image to be visible,  also width if needed. Since there is no content inside that div it will be at 0 height. `div` being a block element will take the full width of its container if not specific width is mentioned.

Example:

```
      element.css({
        'background-image': 'url(https://example.com/' + value + '.jpg)',
        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
        'background-position': 'center center',
        'background-attachment': 'fixed',
        '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
        '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
        '-o-background-size': 'cover',
        'background-size': 'cover',
        'height' :'200px'
      });
```

Set the height and width via css if you have a preset one. If you need to make it flexible calculate the height and width by creating an temp image object.

```
scope.$watch(attrs.backgroundImage, function(value) {
        var url = 'https://example.com/' + value + '.jpg';

        getImageDimensions(url).then(function(dimObj) {

          element.css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + url + ')',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
            'background-position': 'center center',
            height: dimObj.height,
            width: dimObj.width
          });
        })
      });

      function getImageDimensions(url) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function() {

          defer.resolve({height: img.height + 'px', width:img.width + 'px'});
          img = null;
        }

        img.onerror = function(){
          defer.reject("Ivalid url");
          img = null;
        }

        img.src = url;
        return defer.promise;
      }
    };
  }
```